# Hide an Object's Type from Compiler

Tags: c#, java

I was asked this question in an interview. It caught me completely off guard.

You have a super class and a subclass. class `B` is a subclass of `A`. Both classes have an implementation of the same function `foo()`.

**Is it possible to write a piece of code that makes it so that the compiler doesn't know what the type of an object is?** In this case the object is `b` below.

```
A b = new B();
```

Then you would do a function call in which the type won't be known until execution.

This was my answer on the whiteboard: `(A)b.foo();`

Comment: I think that the method is determined on run time .....

Comment: Well yes, that is the idea. I wonder why the downvote.

Comment: Which language is the question about?

Comment: Either Java or C#, which are the two languages this company uses. That is why my tags are [c#] and [java].

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence. What do you mean by "_... maybe something like this won't allow the compiler to know the type: `(A)b.foo();`_"?

Comment: I will change the wording, but that is the code I wrote on the whiteboard as my answer to the interview question.

Comment: May I ask, why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you could use the [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) keyword to achieve dynamic typing.

```
public void MyMethod(dynamic myVar) 
{
    // The compiler don't know the exact type of myVar
    // Does myVar have a foo() method? if not, we get a runtime error.
    myVar.foo();  
}
```

However, I don't think that is the answer they are looking for since `A` and `B` is mentioned (and that it should apply to both Java and C#).

What they might have been looking for (and basically what you are saying yourself) could be something like this:

```
public void MyMethod(A a)
{
    a.foo();    // What foo() method is called? The one from A or the one from B?
}
```

You can use instances of `A` and `B` as the parameter to `MyMethod`, because `B` have an *is-a* relationship (it inherits) with `A`. The compiler sees `a` as an instance of `A` even though it might be an instance of `B`.

What `foo()` method is called? That depends on whether `B` overrides `A`'s implementation of `foo()` or hides it. If it hides it `A`'s method is called and this is determined at compile time and it doesn't matter what type `a` really have.

If it overrides `foo()` (which is most likely the case) then it is determined at runtime. Since the compiler doesn't know the exact type of `a`, the correct method to call is looked up at runtime based on the [*runtime type*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexghi/archive/2009/05/20/compile-time-type-vs-runtime-type-of-a-variable.aspx) of `a`.

So the compiler *do* know the type (it *is-an* `A`), but it does not know the exact type (is it a subclass or not?).

---

As a side note. `(A)b.foo();` will cast the value returned from `foo()` to `A`. If you want to cast `b` to `A` before calling `foo()` you should add an extra set of parentheses: `((A)b).foo();`. However, the cast is unnecessary, since `b` is already declared to be an `A` variable (`A b = ..`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to create an object of some type that the compiler won't know about (which would only be resolved at runtime).

If you are referring to specifically the statement new B(), then no--you are telling the compiler exactly what type is being created.

Answer (score 0):

At least in C# you can use dynamic and the compiler will put in code to determine at runtime what the type is.